# how to copy row if cell has value greater than 0 and paste on another sheet but I want values only, no formulas

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub MoveRows()
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

' Set the source and target sheets
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Procore")
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Budget Line Items")

' Find the last row in the source sheet
lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through each row in the source sheet
For i = 2 To lastRow
' Check if cell in column X contains "a value greater than 0"
If sourceSheet.Cells(i, "H").Value <> 0 Then
' Copy the entire row to the target sheet
sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This code I gathered from another forum post and modified it to fit my application but i need it to paste the values of the rows copied and not the formulas.

Comment: Side notes: `<>0` is not the same as `>0`. Also, consider filtering and then copying visible cells, instead of looping.